# INotifyPropertyChanged targeting C# .Net 3.0

Tags: c#, .net, inotifypropertychanged

I have been working on using mvp to wire up some winforms in C#. UI development is not exactly my strong suite and I was looking for a refactor proof way to implement INotifyPropertyChanged without having to resort to strings to fire change notifications.

The msdn example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx and most of the others I have seen strike me as the wrong way to do it least of all with regards to the fact that the strings have to be changed in case you refactor the properties.

All the other options I have seen on stackoverflow using expressions and func, facilities sadly not available in the legacy solution I am supporting so I was wondering if any one has a way to replicate the current solutions that use expression trees to get the property name.

An example of the solutions I have been seeing.

```
public static string GetPropertyName<T, TReturn>(Expression<Func<T, TReturn>>      expression) 
{
 MemberExpression body = (MemberExpression)expression.Body; return body.Member.Name; 
}
```

Cheers

Comment: ... **refactor proof** ... *really ...really???*

Comment: @Bernard Which examples do you have that you assume are not supported in .NET 3.0? The new features I can think of in 3.5, 4.0 and the upcoming version are parallel extensions, optional and named parameters, dynamics and async, however, none of those seem relevant to the issue.

Comment: @DannyVarod, this is an example of the function I have been seeing around                                                        `public static string GetPropertyName<T, TReturn>(Expression<Func<T, TReturn>> expression)
{
    MemberExpression body = (MemberExpression)expression.Body;
    return body.Member.Name;
}
`

Comment: I am pretty sure that will compile in 3.0.

Comment: @DannyVarod, I have tried it, expression trees were introduced in 3.5 unfortunately http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Are you aware that .NET 3.5 (and 3.0) is built upon 2.0 and that upgrading projects from VS2005 to VS2008 (both C# and C++) is simple (just need to change the number at the top of the csproj/vsproj files) and the new projects can still use old components?

Comment: @DannyVarod, thanks for the reply, unfortunately its not that simple, the solution I am supporting is a framework which specifically requires 3.0 to run because of some dependencies, upgrading the projects will break not only the framework but multiple plugins that require it. I am constrained to 3.0 for all development until such a time that there is a decision to bite the upgrade bullet hence my question on here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For .NET 3.0, your best bet to implement a refactor-proof way of implementing  `INotifyPropertyChanged` is through some form of code-generation. For example, [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/) (an AOP tool) uses IL-weaving to modify the generated assembly in a post-compilation step. You can find a relevant sample for `INotifyPropertyChanged` [here](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/solutions/notifypropertychanged).

By the way, [the state of the art (C# 5) way](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/pavely/archive/2012/03/20/inotifypropertychanged-implementation-with-c-5-0.aspx) of implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`  requires no special tools at all: there's the [`[CallerMemberName]` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Hi Ani, thanks for the example, looks good , I'll try it out and report back.. Cheers !

Comment: you've been very helpful, I tried the PostSharp way in the link you provided but it uses aop inheritance which isn't part of the free distribution. Cheers again

Comment: Ended up doing it the traditional way , as we arent yet on C#5